# R flatten list of vectors by index (without loops)

Tags: r, dplyr

Given a list of vectors, how can I make a new list and fill it with the indexes of the vectors? For example, I need

```
list(c(1), c(1,1,1), c(1,1))
```

to turn into

```
list(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

So one 1 for c(1) (index 1), three 2s for c(1,1,1) (index 2), and two 3s for c(1,1) (index 3). 
Is it possible to do this without a loop? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rep` + `seq_along` + `lengths`:

```
rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst))
# [1] 1 2 2 2 3 3
```

---

`seq_along` gives the index:

```
seq_along(lst)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

`lengths` gives the repeats for each index:

```
lengths(lst)
# [1] 1 3 2
```

Comment: This works perfectly - I wasn't aware the rep() and lengths() functions existed. Thanks!